# Array index out of bounds exception - no obvious reason for exception

Tags: java, arrays, exception, overflow

Good evening gang :) !
Was just wondering if anybody could spot what I am doing wrong here? I have made an array sorter that changes one of the arrays values if duplicates are found. The code is here

```
 for (int j = 0; j < arrayIn.length;  j++){
        int temp = j++;
        if (arrayIn[j] == temp)
            arrayIn[j] = DUPLICATEREMOVE;
    }
```

Where DUPLICATEREMOVE is a final int initialised at 70. I write a simple test program and compile which works as expected, but when I run it throws up an array index out of bounds exception. 
After further digging I also know that if I comment out this line:

```
 arrayIn[j] = DUPLICATEREMOVE;
```

then the program works as expected. So the exception is being thrown from this line. I also have changed the statement to have the constant displayed instead, i.e:

```
arrayIn[j] = 7;
```

The int temp was also an experiment as before the if condition read as:

```
 if (arrayIn[j] == arrayIn[j++])
```

which I thought could have been throwing the error.
I am a little duked into what I am doing wrong so if anybody can spot what I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated :) !
Thanks.

Comment: This could have been trivially spotted if you stepped through your code with a debugger or just a `println` statement. Take the time to learn how to properly debug your code and you will save yourself (and others) a lot of time.

Comment: Your forloop checks if j still is within bounds, but inside the loop you increment it as well. The latter will generate the exception when j == arrayIn.length

Comment: I get the feeling it was caused by ignorance of the ++ operators.  Not only does it return the current int value, it also increments the existing variable.  http://www.freejavaguide.com/increment_decrement_operators.htm

Answer (score 4):

You're incrementing `j` twice. Replace

```
int temp = j++;
```

with

```
int temp = j+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `int temp = j + 1` instead of `j++`? I get the feeling you're incrementing j twice per loop, etc.